# iphone table not updating every time page loads

Tags: iphone

How is it possible to manually refresh a table everytime the table view controller is loaded. i want it to refresh every time the view controller is initialized. My app table only upgrades once the app is closed down and restarted>

Comment: I tried the following iboutlet Uitableview *tableview
And did an @property (nonatomic,retain) iboutlet uitableview *tableView
and i synthesized this in the .m it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

You may override viewWillAppear: method of your ViewController:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)aminated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

**UPDATE:**
you should declare IBOutlet tableView in .h file and connect this outlet to the tableView in the Interface Builder.

Comment: thanks this work however i cant put it under viewWillAppear as it says tableView undeclared. If i put it under didSelectRowAtIndexPath it refreshes once a cell was touched?
so what should i do to make it refresh as u showed me at startup?